# get fields in ajax response

Tags: jquery, json

I send ajax request and get response like this

```
$.post("loadlatestreviews.html", function(data) {
    $("#latest").html(data);
});
```

The response is array of data which looks like this

```
[
 {"subject" : "xxx", "message" : "xxx", "dateTime" : "Mar 5 xxxx"},
 {"subject" : "yyy", "message" : "yyy", "dateTime" : "Mar 5 yyyy"}
]
```

How to read fields `subject`, `message`, `dateTime`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$.each()` jquery method:

```
var data = JSON.parse(data);
$.each(data, function(i, item){
    console.log(item.subject);
    console.log(item.message);
    console.log(item.dateTime);
});
```

---

You have to parse your string first with `JSON.parse(data);` and you have to loop in your data as your response is an array which contains json objects.

Comment: @user1432980 what are you talking about??? If this doesn't work, then what you have posted in question is not actually the response you get...

Comment: @user1432980 are you sure you are getting `json` from your html page?

Comment: @A. Wolff Such error in console: `TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a`

Comment: @Jai yes. Well its full text is - `[{"subject":"xxxx", "message":"xxxxx", "dateTime":"Mar 4 4:37:48 PM", "id" : 1},{"subject":"yyyy", "message":"yyyy", "dateTime":"Mar 5 4:37:48 PM", "id" : 2}]`

Comment: @user1432980 yes that has to be like this because **you are not getting a proper json** out of your html page.

Comment: so you have to parse it with `JSON.parse(data);` then.

Comment: because `JSON.parse();` converts a well formed json string to a well formed json.

Comment: Hm, so $.each does not do it? I thought it operates with returned data as object by default.

Comment: @user1432980 No it doesn't. Anyway here your issue is server side, you should return an object, not a string. This will avoid the need of parsing it to a javascript object client side

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'loadlatestreviews.html'
  method: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    for (d in data) console.log(data[d]);
  }
});
```

This should get you started. Also, if you are not actually sending anything, you can omit the `method: 'POST'` parameter, unless you really need POST.

Let me know how this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each(data, function(i, obj){
    var subj = obj.subject;
    var msg = obj.message;
    var date = obj.dateTime;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the `$.each` method, once you parse the JSON you can access the internal fields by name:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'loadlatestreviews.html'
  method: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var fields = JSON.parse(data);
    var subject = fields["subject"];
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i in data) {
  console.log(data[i]['subject'])
}
```

Comment: You have to tell javascript that your return is JSON type.
It avoids you this line `var data = JSON.parse(data);`

`$.post("loadlatestreviews.html", function(data) {
    $("#latest").html(data);
}, 'json');`

Answer (score 0):

By using $.each() jquery method you can iterate JSON response data.

```
var data = JSON.parse(data);
$.each(data, function(i, itm){
    // You can get each value in loop
    console.log(itm['subject']);
    console.log(itm['message']);
    console.log(itm['dateTime']);
});
```

I hope this answer is useful for you.